# How to Find all SD Cards(Either Internal or External) and Their Corresponding Info in Android?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, mount-point

Hi Android Developers!

Can i enumerate all inserted sd cards and query the following information from a single location(file or folder?):

> 1-)Sdcard's 128bit cid key(which i can obtain from the file under /sys/block/mmcblkK where K is a different number for each sdcard; however there is no way that i can map the id of sdcard to its mount point).
>
> 2-)Sdcard's mount point.

As you can realize that i should fetch both information from the same configuration file or at least there should be something that i can use for mapping sdcard's cid to its corresponding mount point.

Note that, whenever you remove an sdcard and insert it into another device, your mount point changes(it is something device specific, i believe).

Thanks indeed in advance.